# SwiftUI NavigationView show master on left

Tags: swiftui, ios-navigationview

I have some master detail in Swift UI. Here it is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MenuItemView: View {
    var title: String
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    private var btnBack : some View { Button(action: {
        //if landscape just show list on the left
        //same if swipe from left
        //how to do that???


        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }) {
        Text("Menu")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(title)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(title), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: btnBack)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items: [String] = ["Home", "Events", "Topics", "Latest"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: MenuItemView(title: item)) {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("TimelessToday"), displayMode: .inline)

            Text("Initial")
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

This is working exactly as I plan in portrait mode for any IPhone. But in landscape for IPhone 11 or for IPad in portrait I want "Menu" button when pressed to show left menu with list of items. Same like when doing swipe from left side to show it.

Can't understand how to do this.

Comment: To have the same behaviour like the iPhone you could add `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` to your `NavigationView`... The behaviour you would like to have needs to be implemented separately... maybe provide your own `NavigationViewStyle` or make your own `NavigationView` this shouldn't be too hard.